# Prevent `useSelector` from re-rendering component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a table with thousands of rows.

```
import React from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Source from "../components/TranslationTable/Source";

const SourceContainer = React.memo((props) => {

  const suggestionArray = useSelector((state) => state.suggestions.suggestionArray );
  const isFetching = useSelector((state) => state.suggestions.isFetching);

  let source = props.source;

  if (props.shouldHighlight && !isFetching) {
     //I will have code here to highlight text at some point
  }


  return (
    <Source source={source}>{console.log("rendered")}</Source>
  )
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return true;
});

export default SourceContainer;
```

The above component is located inside the first column of each row. When the row is selected, `props.shouldHighlight` becomes true.

The problem that I have is that every single `SourceContainer` component re-renders every time a row is focused. When a row gets focused, `isFetching` becomes true in the redux state, and `suggestionArray` will become equal to an array of suggestions based upon the data in the selected row.

If I remove the `if` statement and the `suggestionArray` variable, the component STILL re-renders. Meaning, the only thing required to re-produce this issue is having an unused `useSelector` variable (`ifFetching`).

Can anyone explain how I can use `useSelector` without re-rendering the component when the state value of that selector changes?

Comment: Can you please make a producible example? You can put your code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq). [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash I have added the relevant code. Also, take note of the existing answer and my response.

Answer (score 4):

Using useSelector, you add a dependency to your Component and it is normal that it re-renders if the content of useSelector changes.

The trick here is to make a less varying content for your useSelector function. Or at least something that changes only if the component needs to re-render

For exemple, from what I understand of what you are trying to achieve, your component should only change if "props.shouldHighlight && !isFetching" changes value.

If that's the case, then what you want to do is this :

```
const isFetching = useSelector((state) => (!state.suggestions.isFetching && props.shouldHighlight));
```

Comment: That solves my problem if that was my only selector. However, I also will require getting the suggestionArray data so that I can highlight all of those words in the component. This  suggestionArray data changes every time a new row is focused as well.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, moving the selector to the parent table and passing the data as a prop would work, would it not? That isn't a very clean solution in my opinion, as the row's parent is a presentational component that should not use selectors. Any ideas on how to keep the useSelector in the row component without this issue?

Comment: The code that i have come up with based on your answer for the suggestionArray is:


`const suggestionArray = useSelector((state) => (props.shouldHighlight ? state.suggestions.suggestionArray : []));`


However, this won't work. I assume this is because of the comparisons between arrays being shallow. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes the shallow comparison is your problem. Create a constant empty array reference before your component (const emptyArray = []) and return it when you want to return the empty array.